# Adjust line spacing after new line

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I would like to adjust the line spacing under a section when I add a new line.

```
 \setlength{\parskip}{}
```

does not work because it only changes the spaces between sections, not between newlines (`\\`). For example, I would like for this source to have the first two lines as they are, while the last two sentences separated by an arbitrary distance:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

%\setlength{\parskip}{1cm} %this command does not solve the problem
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet nibh
convallis, interdum dui vitae, ultrices urna. \\Vestibulum lobortis, mi vitae
hendrerit pulvinar, nunc mauris dapibus dui, sed hendrerit mauris leo in magna. 
\end{document}
```

Could anybody please tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: `\\[3in]` would add some space, but really you should try to avoid all forced linebreaks in a document.

Comment: Why do you want a gap mid-paragraph? How is the reader supposed to know it is the same paragraph? setting `\parskip` changes the space between paragraphs (not between sections as you state in the question)

Comment: \parskip gives me spaces between sections. I want the user to spot a new line without indenting the following line. I just want the document to have some space when new lines occur, pretty much like using vspace, but by using double backslash.

Comment: But what do you mean by "new line" Tex breaks the paragraph into lines, do you want additional space there? (that interline spacing can be changed if needed) `\\ ` is a linebreak within the same paragraph so it is _very_ unusual to force extra space there, it is just manual control over the linebreak if the automatic algorithm is having difficulty to find a good break, you don't normally want to highlight that in the output. If the following text is logically a new paragraph `\\ ` is the wrong markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The markup for a paragraph break is a blank line, not `\\` :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}


\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet nibh
convallis, interdum dui vitae, ultrices urna.

Vestibulum lobortis, mi vitae
hendrerit pulvinar, nunc mauris dapibus dui, sed hendrerit mauris leo in magna. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this solution only works in `\documentclass{article}`? I'm trying to use your solution with my problem, but I have `\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}` in overleaf. Does it requires another solution?

Comment: @Chris beamer uses paragraph spacing by default so there should not be a problem to solve in that case. But the site doesn't really support asking questions as comments on old answers, if you have a beamer question post with a small example as a new question.